# Rails 6.0 Seed.rb file not saving to sqlite3 db after running rails db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, seed

Rails 6.0 (Beginner level)
My seed file does not save into my db after running `rails db:seed --trace`

I get the following output :

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

As it states to abort if pending migrations. I ran rails db:migrate just to be safe, but it they are all up to date, so nothing was done.

Is there something in the `load_config` I need to do?

Note: I have through this process created 2 entries into this table while trying to get this to work. Would prior entries in the table block the seed from working?

Seedfile below

```
def time_rand from = 0.0, to = Time.now
    Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f))
end

  event_list = [
    ["My headline", 
    "this is a very long description of text", 
    "Physical Location", 
    "Locations url", 
    time_rand, 
    "this is a shorter description of words", 
    "https://www.ticketmaster.com/", 
    "google maps url",
    "123 Fake Street", 
    "Brooklyn", 
    "11123", 
    "NY", 
    "USA" ]
]

event_list.each do |headline, d_long, location_name, location_url, image_url, time, d_short, tickets_url, map_url, location_street, location_city, location_zip, location_state, location_country|
    temp = Event.create(
                headline: headline, 
                description_long: d_long, 
                location_name: location_name, 
                location_url: location_url, 
                time: time, 
                description_short: d_short, 
                tickets_url: tickets_url, 
                map_url: map_url, 
                location_street: location_street,
                location_city: location_city,
                location_zip: location_zip,
                location_state: location_state,
                location_country: location_country
    )
    temp.save
end
```

EDIT:
Thanks Sebastian for calling out Model validations.
Though I think I'm still fulfilling the validations, here the model file is :

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    validates :headline, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
    validates :description_short, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
    validates :location_name, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
end
```

Comment: That's the common trace for the `rails db:seed` command. Can you check you're not really succeeding in persisting those records in the db? Are they being validated in the model, or database constraints?

Comment: I have no validations in the Model file. And as the seed file doesn't use the Controller I don't have to worry about any conditions from the Controller or View when using the seed.rb file. I have just dropped and migrated the DB again. Ran the seed file on an empty DB. Run Event.all inside the rails console: Still empty.

Comment: I am not aware of any constraints from the db itself. Are there any default settings that prevents seed file or similar?

Comment: You can debug the logic in the `each` blog. Try replacing the `create` method for `new` and before the save put `byebug` (or `binding.pry`), that will stop the execution and allow you to work at that context.

Comment: Try `temp.valid?` to check if the object is able to be saved.

Comment: Hm... Hold on for a bit. I am getting errors in the rails console when not filling in certain columns....

Comment: @SebastianPalma, I ended up with nil time. It always returned nil until I realized that I was missing the image_url in the Event.new(... but not in the event_list.each. I would never have figured it out w/out byebug. Please update with a proper answer. Wouldn't have figured it out this fast w/out your help.

Comment: Glad to help, and don't worry. I encourage you to add your own answer, as detailed so you can come back and realize what you did to solve the problem, and help newcomers as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sebastian Palma's suggestion to **use the byebug** I figured it out:
-I had a miss count of params so the time was given a string.
-I also was given a nil by the temp.time and therefore rejected by the validation.
I ended up just **hardcoding in some time value to make sure it passed** in the end.

Lesson learned : Count your param's & use byebug